# What is the tbauth:// protocol?

Tags: outlook, protocols

I think that Outlook uses it to get passwords because I saw this error message recently:

[image]

I have never seen this tbauth protocol and am curious what it is. Googling doesn't help much - the top result is a link to https://windows10dll.nirsoft.net/tbauth_dll.html which is about a DLL that has "tbauth protocol handler" in its description.

What is it used for, is it used only by Outlook, is it a public API or something internal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TBAuth is a Single Sign-On (SSO) protocol - note this reference in the Windows registry, pointing to the tbauth.dll you mention:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{14654CA6-5711-491D-B89A-58E571679951}]
@="Microsoft TBAuth Single-Sign On Protocol"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{14654CA6-5711-491D-B89A-58E571679951}\InProcServer32]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\tbauth.dll"
```

The TB stands for Token Broker - [this Word document](https://download.microsoft.com/download/F/C/A/FCA7C6E3-7153-4FB1-9825-0B1BB26F14E0/Azure-AD-Windows-10-better-together.docx) on Azure Active Directory mentions it on page 59:

> Token Broker in Windows 10 is a new authentication framework that
>   improves upon the former Web Application Broker in Windows 8.x and
>   which is designed to provide Single Sign-On (SSO) for browser, modern
>   business applications, and services.